# Fill na by applying condition on another column

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

There is a df which contains two columns. First column has monthly values but the second one only contains quarterly values. I want to fill the NA values of second column by the same percentage change on the first column. For example, the original df looks like this:

```
            ColA   ColB 
2019-12-31   100    5
2020-01-31   200    NA
2020-02-28   300    NA
2020-03-31   200    20
2020-04-30   300    NA
```

And I want to calculate the percentage change of colA and then fill the colB as per the percentage change. The result should look like:

```
            ColA   ColB 
2019-12-31   100    5
2020-01-31   200    10
2020-02-28   300    15
2020-03-31   200    20
2020-04-30   300    30
```

I can calculate the percentage changes of colA by `pct_change()` but not getting the point how to apply only on the na values of colB. Is there any solution for it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply compute a ratio, ffill it, and use combine_first to update missing values:

```
ratio = (df['ColB'] / df['ColA']).ffill()
df['ColB'] = df['ColB'].combine_first(df['ColA'] * ratio)
```

It is enough to get the expected result:

```
            ColA  ColB
2019-12-31   100   5.0
2020-01-31   200  10.0
2020-02-28   300  15.0
2020-03-31   200  20.0
2020-04-30   300  30.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First idea is create `percenta change` column and inverse percentage change by `ColB` - first value.

```
df['pct'] = df['ColA'].pct_change()

df['ColB'] = df['pct'].add(1,fill_value=0).cumprod().mul(df.loc[df.index[0], 'ColB'])
print (df)
            ColA  ColB       pct
2019-12-31   100   5.0       NaN
2020-01-31   200  10.0  1.000000
2020-02-28   300  15.0  0.500000
2020-03-31   200  10.0 -0.333333
2020-04-30   300  15.0  0.500000
```

If possible create groups and get percentage per groups defined non missing values in `ColB` use:

```
df['g'] = df['ColB'].notna().cumsum()
df['pct'] = df.groupby('g')['ColA'].pct_change()

df['ColB'] = df.groupby('g')['pct'].transform(lambda x: x.add(1,fill_value=0).cumprod().mul(df.loc[x.index[0], 'ColB']))
print (df)
            ColA  ColB  g  pct
2019-12-31   100   5.0  1  NaN
2020-01-31   200  10.0  1  1.0
2020-02-28   300  15.0  1  0.5
2020-03-31   200  20.0  2  NaN
2020-04-30   300  30.0  2  0.5
```